# SharePoint workflow on update Calendar item category change

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have 2 SharePoint Designer workflows one works when an item is created, it creates an calendar event. A field Change Outcome is left empty.

In the second workflow when the item has been updated and the field Change Outcome is set to approve then a new calendar event gets created which category is set as approved and the category uses Green color so it can be seen easily in the calendar that which items are approved.

But I want the same event to change the category and I have tried from my side but couldn't get through it.

I am attaching the screenshots with the post.
[image]

[image]

Comment: what it the problem? it is not clear

Comment: Raf- I want to modify the calendar Category to Proceed if the following statement is true:

If Current Item:CAB Advisory to Relase Manager equals Proceed 
then change item in ITS Change calendar and set the category to Proceed

This is what I am intended to do but couldn't.

Comment: At the moment I am creating new item whenever the item has been updated and the statement If current Item:CAB Advisory to Release Manager equals to Proceed. So then there are two new items in the calendar I want just one.

Comment: Are you trying to change the category of the same list item on which the workflow is running (after item is updated)? If Yes, are you not able to update the category using **Update item** action?

Comment: Hi Ganesh, No, they are two different lists that's why the Update action is not working. If it would've been the same list then I am sure Update the category would have worked. Create Item works but it creates a new event in the calendar instead of modifying or deleting the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly You need to configure workflow to change category of existing calendar item after changing of current item.

To do this you can:

1. Create additional column in calendar list(it can be hidden column),for example - *CAB_id*
2. Put current item ID into CAB_id

Then, add additional steps in your workflow that fires when item changes:

1. Send HTTP request to get filtered elements from calendar as described [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/58e23e/call-http-web-service-using-sharepoint-designer-2013-spd/) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5b22c95e-0ad5-45ed-8c70-698409cd9c69/workflow-query-list?forum=sharepointcustomization)
2. Change category

Comment: It seems to be like very difficult process. I was thinking of doing it straightaway. Like making a additional column in the calendar list and then setting it as No and on update of the item it should says Yes and then perform this action. Is there possibility of this option or anything simpler ?