# How to create index variable in SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, workflow, site, index-component

I am creating a Call HTTP Web service in SharePoint Designer 2013 and looking to create a index variable but don't know how can I ?

Is the local variable and the index variable same?

Comment: You may need to create a new workflow variable of number and then use it for n times(number of results from REST API).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps:

1. Create a new workflow variable (say `indexloop`).
2. Set its value to 0.
3. Add loop until the `indexloop` is less than the number of results returned from REST API.

Check below link for detailed explanation and images:

[SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflows and GET REST API](https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2017/06/25/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflows-and-get-rest-api/)

**Documentation**:

[Working with Web Services in SharePoint Workflows using SharePoint Designer 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/working-with-web-services-in-sharepoint-workflows-using-sharepoint-designer).

**Additional references**:

1. [Looping on List Items in SharePoint Designer Workflow 2013](http://www.kopisusa.com/looping-on-list-items-in-sharepoint-designer-workflow-2013/).
2. [SharePoint 2013: Designer Workflow To Iterate Through REST API Results Using Loop](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32815.sharepoint-2013-designer-workflow-to-iterate-through-rest-api-results-using-loop.aspx)

Comment: Cool. I am trying to change the calendar start Date / Time if changed in a list but it doesn't change in the calendar list. So, I am trying for this. Do you have any little guidance regarding this method if it's useful and it will work whenever a change has been made in the list it will change the calendar list start date/time as well?

Comment: Means that will the rest API will work for what I intend to do. As I have tried various other ways in the SharePoint designer which can create a new event in the calendar but it doesn't change the category of an event which is already there. Can you check my post regarding that. It will be useful to me as I am working on it at the moment.

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277492/sharepoint-workflow-on-update-calendar-item-category-change

Comment: This is the link to my post. A guy mentioned a similar method like yours but as I am not very good and doing it for the first time so need a little more details. As you answered my questions from the starting, so you know I am a beginner and this is more complicated for me.